# How to avoid that "git gc" generates garbage loose objects?

Tags: git, git-gc

Before I ran `git gc`, I had a few thousand loose objects:

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 3706
size: 17164
in-pack: 147149
packs: 9
size-pack: 46619
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

(note the loose object `count` and `size`). After `git gc` I had more of it:

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 6735
size: 19687
in-pack: 142215
packs: 1
size-pack: 43373
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

I know that this happens because `git gc` evicts objects from packs when they become unreachable; it gives them a new "lease of life" as loose objects.

How can I avoid that this single behavior of `git gc` happens? I want all its other behaviors to remain, i.e., all timeouts, all sorts of garbage removals, everything except this one.

I run `git gc` monthly at most. For some reason that I do not know, `git gc --auto` barely ever runs (and I do not want to change that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're *sure* no other Git command is running in that repository at the time you run `git gc` on that repository, you can add `--prune=all`.  The default is `--prune=2.weeks.ago`, which gives those other running commands 14 days to complete their work; you can use `--prune=1.day.ago` to give them less time, for instance.

You can also configure `gc.pruneExpire`: if not set, it defaults to `2.weeks.ago` which is what produces the above default.  As [j6t notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414916/how-to-avoid-that-git-gc-generates-garbage-loose-objects/55418759?noredirect=1#comment97615443_55418759), the `gc.pruneExpire` setting variant of this is `now` rather than `all`.  It's unwise to set `now` here though: an automatic `git gc` will use this value *and* will run in the background, while other Git operations run.

Note that if you have a version of Git >= 2.5 but below 2.15.0, a reduced `gc.pruneExpire` can break your added work-trees in less time than the default two weeks.  The bug is that `git gc` fails to use the `HEAD` and index of the added work-tree as a starting point for the reachability traversal of the object DAG.  As a result, `git gc` can remove added blobs that have not yet been committed, and, if you have a worktree with a detached HEAD, even some commits.  The *best* fix for this is to upgrade to 2.15.0 or later, since even the 2-week default isn't necessarily enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I set `gc.pruneExpire` to `now` as `all` is just an unparsable date that happens to be interpreted as `now` (and that might change in a future version of Git).

Comment: A word of _warning_ to readers stumbling across this post: If you are using `git worktree` and a Git before version 2.15.0, `git gc` can break your secondary worktrees with or without setting `gc.pruneExpire`. But setting it to `now` makes it is *much* easier to shoot yourself in the foot!

Comment: Interesting. I was going to use `now` but the documentation said to use `all` (!). This might be because setting `pruneExpire` to `now` is unwise (see edit). And yes, gc-ing with added worktrees breaks in 2.5 through (but not including) 2.15.0; I ran into this one myself.

Comment: `pruneExpire` specifies a time. There was a [discussion recently](https://public-inbox.org/git/alpine.LFD.2.21.1903020323110.16672@localhost.localdomain/t/#m590704d2a03f527783496824823598d16b998d60) that the documentation is at least imprecise when it says `all`. It should really be `now`.